# hbm2ddl.auto is update but still creating the table in the database

Tags: hibernate

When I'm creating the Hibernate application for first time and in the cfg.xml file, declared property hbm2ddl.auto as update , but it is still creating table instead throwing Exception "Table/View does not exits"

property name="hbm2ddl.auto" update

As per the value "update", if the table is already exits it has to update the data and it should not create the table in the DB(oracle).

But , in my case I declare "update" and no table exists in the DB but creating the table instead throwing Exception.

Can any one suggest me on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want Hibernate to do nothing to your schema, set `hbm2ddl.auto` to `none`.

Answer (score 0):

The value of "update" still updates the schema (and will keep creating your table). Removing `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` entirely will probably accomplish what you're looking for.

Check out this guy for more info on the other values:
[Hibernate hbm2ddl.auto possible values and what they do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/438146/hibernate-hbm2ddl-auto-possible-values-and-what-they-do/1689769#1689769)

Comment: I agreee, by removing hbm2ddl.auto we can achieve but my concern is if the value is update it should not create the table in the DB then  why it is still creating the table in the DB?